# Помимо id получаю index.css в req.params.id

Tags: node.js

По какой причине может быть, что в этот req.params.id сперва попадает настоящее id, а сразу после него "index.css", который я подключаю в main layout'е?

```
const { Router } = require('express')
const router = Router()

router.get('/:id', async (req, res) => {
  const item = await ShopModel.getById(req.params.id)
  res.render('item', {
    title: item.title,
    item
  })
})
```

Пробовал устанавливать начальную папку перед routes, ничего не поменялось:

```
app.use(express.static('public'))
app.use('/', homeRoutes)
app.use('/shop', shopRoutes)
```

Подключение head:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./index.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

Когда убрал точку перед index.css всё стало работать, как надо:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/index.css">
```